# Change an image of ImageButton permenantly when do something

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, imagebutton

As above, I want to change an image of ImageButton when do some event (clicked or few seconds later).

```
void OnclkMe(GameObject go)
{
    go.GetComponentInChildren<UISprite>().spriteName = "NumCard_01";
}
```

When I clicked the button, It looks like work well, but the changed image was re-changed to first image when a mousepoint move out of button.

I tested the spriteName using Debug.Log func, and I checked that sprite was re-changed automatically.

How can I change an image of ImageButton when occur some of event permanently ?

Comment: Make sure that `NumCard_01` exist in the atlast. Also, it is case sensitive. If this is a new project, you should not use NGUI. You need to use the new Unity UI. Exception is when your whole game is already made with NGUI.

Comment: NumCard_01 exists in atlas. and I used NGUI because I want to reduce development period.... But... is this come back to haunt me? My project is an initial stage yet..

Comment: It looks like. It can be discontinued anytime if many people adopt the Unity's uGUI. I used to use `Daikon Forge`. It was awesome but I switched to Unity's UI immediately after it came out. Months later, `Daikon Forge` got discontinued and is no longer updated. The fact is that if people stop buying it, there will be no time and resources for the publisher to continue to update it.

Answer (score 1):

For new projects, you should use uGUI which is Unity's new UI system.

You can register to button event with `Button.onClick.AddListener(() => callbackFunction())` and you can change the sprite in the button's image with `Button.image.sprite = newSprite;`. You need to include `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of your script.

```
public Button button1;
public Button button2;

public Sprite newSprite;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
    button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));
}

private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    if (buttonPressed == button1)
    {
        //Your code for button 1
        buttonPressed.image.sprite = newSprite;
    }

    if (buttonPressed == button2)
    {
        //Your code for button 2
    }
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    button2.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: Is equally performant to do the `AddListener` anonymous function than an event ?

Comment: @P0lT10n It is better to use event in Unity anytime you can because its performance is better. `AddListener` is made to make it easier to make event with Buttons. There is no performance loss by using `AddListener` because you don't click a Button 2 million times per-second.